# ansible play gives UndefinedError: 'dict object'

Tags: ansible, jinja2

**Getting following error when running ansible play:**

TASK [Render configuration using e3_template file] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: ansible.errors.AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute 'interface'. 'dict object' has no attribute 'interface'
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute 'interface'. 'dict object' has no attribute 'interface'"}

**Variable defined in j2 template with index of 0:**

interface {{ interfaces[0].interface }}
description Mgmt
ip address {{ interfaces[0].ip_address }}
no shut
!

**variable defined in vars file:**

interfaces:

- interface: vlan 98
  ip_address: 1.2.3.4/28
- interface: vlan 100
- interface: vlan 200
- interface: vlan 300

Answer (score 2):

Please note that the input you provided is not valid YAML. In YAML, dictionaries should be represented using key-value pairs separated by colons (:) and not with spaces as shown. The corrected YAML representation of the interfaces variable would be:

```yaml
---
- name: Test
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    interfaces:
      - interface: vlan 98
        ip_address: 1.2.3.4/28
      - interface: vlan 100
      - interface: vlan 200
      - interface: vlan 300
  tasks:
    - ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "interface {{ interfaces[0].interface }} description Mgmt ip address {{ interfaces[0].ip_address }} no shut !"
```

```yaml
TASK [ansible.builtin.debug] ****************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "interface vlan 98 description Mgmt ip address 1.2.3.4/28 no shut !"
}
```